# Resources for learning Play for Scala

Tags: scala, playframework

This site has questions on how to develop Play for Java, but its tough to find the same for Scala. What are the high-quality (atleast complete) resources to learn Play other than the official documentation?

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/ScalaHome